# populate menu multilevel from a table

Tags: php, mysql, multi-level

I made a query

```
"SELECT * FROM products"
```

which I can use to populate a table with following theads using all rows of that query.

```
(id_category) (id_brand) (id_size)
```

Now I am trying to create a multilevel unordered list from this populated table. Is it possible to do it? Result should like this:

**Category Name**

```
 Brand name for above Category

 Size name for above Brand and Category
```

Comment: List from Table?? I dont understand what is it you want.